# Difficulty in solving characteristic equations.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> How to solve following characteristics equations ?
>
> $$\frac{dx}{xa_{{1}}+ya_{{2}}} = \frac{dy}{-xa_{{2}}+ya_{{1}}} = \frac{dz}{a_{1}z} = \frac{dt}{a_{1}t} = \frac{du}{-ua_{{1}}+va_{{9}}} = \frac{dv}{-ua_{{9}}-va_{{1}}} = \frac{d\psi}{a_{{1}} \left( -2\,w-2 \right)}$$

here $u,v$ and $w$ may be taken as dependent variables depending on $x,y,z$ and $t$. I need solution like $F(c_{1},\dots,c_{6})$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{dx}{xa_{{1}}+ya_{{2}}} = \frac{dy}{-xa_{{2}}+ya_{{1}}} = \frac{dz}{a_{1}z} = \frac{dt}{a_{1}t} = \frac{du}{-ua_{{1}}+va_{{9}}} = \frac{dv}{-ua_{{9}}-va_{{1}}} = \frac{d\psi}{a_{{1}} \left( -2\,w-2 \right)}$$

The symbol $\psi$ isn't defined. I suppose that there is a typo and that the last term is : $= \frac{dw}{a_{{1}} \left( -2\,w-2 \right)}$

If there was no typo, that is if $\psi\neq w$ , the wording of the question would be incomplete. A relationship would be missing between $\psi$ and the other functions. The solving couldn't be fully carried out.

If the supposition $\psi=w$ is true, the equations of six characteristic curves are derived below :

[image]